# Windows CMD expand filename if file has .double.extension

Tags: string, batch-file, file-extension

I'm writing a script that converts a Markdown file to a PDF, facilitated by Pandoc.

So if you drag `C:\Users\User\Documents\English\PAPER1.md` onto the script, it'll create `C:\Users\User\Documents\English\PDFs\PAPER1.pdf`.

This is achieved in the header of the script via

```
set INPUT=%1
set PDFDIR=%~dp1\PDFs
set PDF=%PDFDIR%\%~n1.pdf
```

However, in certain circumstances, the input filename will be `Something.md.txt`, in which case I only still want to output `Something.pdf`. (Removing more than three extensions will probably not be necessary or desirable.)

But the current setup only strips one extension, producing `Something.md.pdf`.

However, `%~nn1.pdf` does not work, nor does `set p=%~n1` `set PDF=%~np`, giving

```
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~np
```

How do I get the bare filename of a file with "two extensions"?

Comment: This works with one _or_ two extensions: `for %%a in ("%filename%") do for %%b in ("%%~Na") do set "newName=%%~Nb.pdf"`

Comment: Assuming your file name does not have any periods you actually need in the file name: `FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=." %%G IN ("%~nx1")  do set name=%%G`

Answer (score 1):

I'd change every line from the provided header of the script to:

```bat
Set "INPUT=%~1"
Set "PDFDIR=%~dp1PDFs"
For %%A In ("%~dpn1") Do Set "PDF=%PDFDIR%\%%~nA.pdf"
```

Because there's no surety of the input content, please use best practice and always reference these variables wherever possible using doublequotes:

```bat
Echo "%INPUT%"
Echo "%PDFDIR%"
Echo "%PDF%"
```